# To live just outside of (somewhere)

Tags: meaning

I often hear native English speakers say: *(someone) lives just outside of (a city)* to indicate their place of residence.

Does "just outside of" mean in an adjacent city, in the outer part of the city mentioned or something else?

Comment: In the UK we usually say, *just outside (somewhere)*, without the "of".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means near that city, but not in it. The name of the city is being used to identify the general area where the person lives because the city's name is well-known and likely to be recognized by the person being spoken to. It has the same meaning as "in the vicinity of".